# How to do sampling in requests

Tags: java, sampling

From System A I want to send certain requests to System B.
System B should get some small percentage of random requests from System A.
Irrespective of traffic on system A, how do I sample requests at specific rate to send to B? Sampling preferred for randomization.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with ? The code to select X % of your requests ? The system architecture ? The redirection of JMS, HTTP, GRPC or whichever kind of requests  your system uses ?

Comment: Your question needs more focus, please narrow your question to one specific issue. As for how you do what you want, It entirely depends on your project structure, and what you are using to communicate between systems (Database? Sockets? Web API? Shared File Storage?). Hint: Rather than asking general open questions, ask specific targeted questions, or use a search engine to look for specific terms like "java communicate with another PC" and "java generate random number from a range". But again it entirely depend on your project structure...